# Simple tabulary table overflows columns

Tags: tables, tabulary

I want to create a simple table with tabulary:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabulary}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{|L|L|L|}
A & B & C
\\
Blablab & Blablablabl & Blabl bl bla blabl blablabl blabl blabl bl blab blab bla blabla bl blablabla bla blabla
\\
\end{tabulary}

\end{document}
```

But the generated columns are a mess. The first two columns are not big enough. The words overflow into the next columns.

```
Overfull \hbox (10.59239pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 12--12
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 Blablab|

Overfull \hbox (16.04956pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 12--12
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 Blablablabl|

Overfull \hbox (15.00195pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 12--13
[][]
```

What is the best way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Blablablabl` is too big and tex doesn't hyphenate that. You can over come this by specifying

```
\tymin=60pt
\tymax=\maxdimen
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabulary,showframe}  %% showframe just for demo
\tymin=60pt
\tymax=\maxdimen
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{|L|L|L|}
A & B & C
\\
Blablab & Blablablabl & Blabl bl bla blabl blablabl blabl blabl bl blab blab bla blabla bl blablabla bla blabla
\\
\end{tabulary}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use of column specifier `l` from `tabular` for the first two columns.
and use of `\noindent` right before `tabulary` environment.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{|l|l|L|}
A & B & C\\
Blablab & Blablablabl & Blabl bl bla blabl blablabl blabl blabl bl blab blab bla blabla bl blablabla bla blabla\\
\end{tabulary}

\end{document}
```